# Should I cancel an onsite tech interview if I'm sick?

Tags: interviewing, tech-industry, onsite

Should I let them know and try to reschedule? Go take the interview even if it means hours of sniffing and sneezing?

Comment: Are you going to call into work every time you get a cold?

Comment: My current boss always tells us to stay home if we're sick, so I know for a fact some people get disgusted and/or don't want the germs in the office

Comment: Can the tickets be rescheduled?

Answer (score 4):

I would use the same judgment as I would if this were an important conference / meeting. Are you so sick that it would significantly affect your working ability to the point where you would just be wasting time? If this were a regular work day, would you get medical leave or would you travel to work anyway?

With that said, I think there are several actions you can do to make the situation better:

- Inform them via email that you are sick, but do not come to conclusion whether you will reject the interview yet. Give yourself (and them) some options. Perhaps you will get better (you never know). Perhaps they propose a reschedule.
- Ask if they can shorten the interview duration, considering your health condition. They may or may not, but it never hurts to ask.
- If you have to attend the interview, wear a mask. Have a bag ready for your personal hygiene matters. It would show that you have prepared and you care for those people in the same room with you, rather than spreading germs in a irresponsible manner.

Comment: *"If you have to attend the interview, wear a mask."* I would avoid doing this. If you are not in an environment where a surgical mask is relatively common, it is going to come across as weird. If you are so sick that you would need a surgical mask and a garbage bag you are going to be off-putting, it is best to just beg for a reschedule at that point.